# How to to swap columns in table?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I change place blue column with others, like to make blue column on the far right side?

Please see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meg4s.png).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/fillable_area">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            >
             <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/fixed_column"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

             <HorizontalScrollView
               android:id="@+id/scroller"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/scrollable_part"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            </HorizontalScrollView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My code:

```
package com.example.freez_t00;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean showSummaries;

    private TableLayout summaryTable;
    private TableLayout frozenTable;
    private TableLayout contentTable;
    private Button backButton ;
    private HorizontalScrollView hor;
      private TextView recyclableTextView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           TableRow.LayoutParams wrapWrapTableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            int[] fixedColumnWidths = new int[]{20, 20,20, 20, 20};
            int[] scrollableColumnWidths = new int[]{20, 20, 20, 30, 30};
            int fixedRowHeight = 50;
            int fixedHeaderHeight = 60;
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            //header (fixed vertically)
            TableLayout header=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_header);
            row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapTableRowParams);
            row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col1", fixedColumnWidths[0],fixedHeaderHeight));
            row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col2", fixedColumnWidths[1],fixedHeaderHeight));
            row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col3", fixedColumnWidths[2],fixedHeaderHeight));
            row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col4", fixedColumnWidths[3],fixedHeaderHeight));
            row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col5", fixedColumnWidths[4],fixedHeaderHeight));
            header.addView(row);
            hor = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroller);
            hor.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    hor.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                }
            }, 1L);

            TableLayout fixedColumn = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.fixed_column);
            //rest of the table (within a scroll view)
            TableLayout scrollablePart = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollable_part);

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                TextView fixedView = makeTableRowWithText("row number " + i, scrollableColumnWidths[0], fixedRowHeight);

                fixedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                fixedColumn.addView(fixedView);

               row = new TableRow(this);
               row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapTableRowParams);
               row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
               row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
               row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 2", scrollableColumnWidths[1], fixedRowHeight));
               row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 3", scrollableColumnWidths[2], fixedRowHeight));
               row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 4", scrollableColumnWidths[3], fixedRowHeight));
               row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 5", scrollableColumnWidths[4], fixedRowHeight));
               scrollablePart.addView(row);


            }

       }

     public TextView makeTableRowWithText(String text, int widthInPercentOfScreenWidth, int fixedHeightInPixels) {
            int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            recyclableTextView = new TextView(this);
            recyclableTextView.setText(text);
            recyclableTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            recyclableTextView.setTextSize(20);
            recyclableTextView.setWidth(widthInPercentOfScreenWidth * screenWidth / 100);
            recyclableTextView.setHeight(fixedHeightInPixels);
            return recyclableTextView;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to loop through all the `TableRows` and swap their views. For example, to swap first and second columns:

```
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollable_part);
        int sourceColumnIndex = 0;
        int targetColumnIndex = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = (TableRow)table.getChildAt(i);
            View v = tr.getChildAt(sourceColumnIndex);
            tr.removeViewAt(sourceColumnIndex);
            tr.addView(v, targetColumnIndex);
        }
```

EDIT:
I did check it in my own little project. I see now that in your project, the swapped views have different parents. I changed your code to add 'TableRow' even for the fixed part:

```
    row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapTableRowParams);
    row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    row.addView(fixedView);
    fixedColumn.addView(row);
```

And after that swap routine is:

```
                TableLayout fixedColumnTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.fixed_column);
                TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollable_part);
                if (table.getChildCount() == fixedColumnTable.getChildCount())
                {
                    int fixedColumnIndex = 0;
                    int targetColumnIndex = 2;
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++)
                    {
                        TableRow fixedTR = (TableRow)fixedColumnTable.getChildAt(i);
                        View fixedView = fixedTR.getChildAt(fixedColumnIndex);

                        TableRow targetTR = (TableRow)table.getChildAt(i);
                        View targetView = targetTR.getChildAt(targetColumnIndex);

                        fixedTR.removeViewAt(fixedColumnIndex);
                        targetTR.removeViewAt(targetColumnIndex);
                        fixedTR.addView(targetView, fixedColumnIndex);
                        targetTR.addView(fixedView, targetColumnIndex);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for you , but i tray to copy your code and past in my project ater for loop but No change in places columns                                               Did you try this code already ?
Did you succeeded ?

Comment: Excuse me, brother
I have tried but without result
look here:

Comment: Thnks for you , but not worked I want to always be a constant blue column Anywhere You can add code,i Added in more than one place does not work ,Remember that I want to be a constant blue column in the right side
And I want to know places type the code exactly
And thank you